# Regex not working for similar input

Tags: regex

I have the inputs:

1. `url=http://www.diffusiononline.co.uk/women-c1/coats-jackets-c133/barbour-international-quilted-womens-jacket-bright-pink-p14973/s30548?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=barbour-international-quilted-women-039-s-jacket-bright-pink-size-6-colour-brightpink-66352179002&utm_campaign=product+listing+ads`
2. `url=http://www.hurleys.co.uk/womens-c85/jackets-coats-c125/barbour-international-barbour-international-womens-black-dera-vulcan-waxed-jacket-p85604/s415845`

Regex

`/url=(?!.*url)(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?([^?\/]+)?(\/\S*)/`

For the first input, I am able to get two matches, but for the second input none.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to state what you want, what you're getting, and what you've tried.

Comment: What doesn't work again? When did it not work before?

Comment: The negative lookahead `(?!.*url)` means that `url` is not allowed anywhere in the URL. Get rid of that if you don't want it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the negative lookahead

```
(?!.*url)
```

to:

```
(?!.*url=)
```

That will make it stop when it gets to another `url=` prefix, not at `hurley` in the domain.

Comment: More precisely, it prevents a match altogether if there is more than one `url=` in the input string. Also, word boundary anchors might help (`\burl=`)  if you could expect query strings like `hurl=`...